# Photoshop, How to replace colors overlapping over other colors and maintain the Levels without manually swapping the RGB Channels in Channels?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, mask, blending, grayscale

I am trying to figure out how one can select an area and get a grayscale as a result. But I don't even know what to do with the grayscale.

I have created a simple gradient, **to create an example for this question**.

[image: Gradient 1]

And I want to turn it into this gradient.

[image: Gradient 2]

This would be straight forward, you'd just swap the red channel with the blue channel.

Yes, this would be that. But what I want to obtain from this question, is to figure out an alternative way.

Modifying the Channels directly, ***seems destructive** if you have something entirely different*.

*What if there wasn't only green, but also yellow and you want to turn the red accurately into blue?*

This is why I want to figure out a different method, that solves that question.

I have tried taking the red mask, and tried to do Layer Blending with a RGB (0, 0, 255) color *(full blue)*.

But it's not giving the output at all, and still keeps red.

What is the way, that focuses on the question regarding what if there would be yellow or any other color? *(If you have an answer that isn't destructive for the one without the yellow then it answers the question as well)*

Like, turning this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

but not destructive, or just a section of it by using a mask

This question should aim for solving situations where you want to colorize something and manually selecting the area. And a color could be overlapping with another. If you'd fully put a white pixel in the mask, the colorize strenght would be more than what it is on the original image.

Comment: Switching channels is nondestructive. The result might be weird, but it is totally reversible.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are looking for Adjustment Layers. These are a non-destructive way of applying edits, and they come with a layer mask which you can edit to exclude certain areas.

Here's an example using the Channel Mixer as an Adjustment Layer, with a mask applied to limit the adjustment to the red area only. The button highlighted in red is where you can find and add Adjustment Layers.

[image]

Another method would be to use a hue-saturation adjustment layer.

https://imgur.com/4KCwteN

To edit the layer mask, select the layer mask thumbnail in the layer adjustment to highlight it. Make a selection and fill it with black. Areas which are black will not have the adjustment applied. Alternatively, you can also make a selection before adding a layer adjustment, and it will be added to the mask automatically.

As for the Channel Mixer, here are the settings I used for the red green and blue channels. Obviously you can tweak these as you like.

[image]

**EDIT** You could also use a Hue-Saturation adjustment layer similarly.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there still red left?

Comment: @karl-police - what do you mean?  Can you see any red in the image?  The original layer hasn't been changed. The change is applied using a layer adjustment. If you hide the adjustment layer, you will see the original is unaffected. The adjustment layer is basically swapping most of the red channel for blue.

Comment: @karl-police You could also use a Hue-Saturation adjustment layer for a similar effect. [see example](https://imgur.com/4KCwteN).

Comment: I see red. I don't want to simply turn it into blue. I want to precisely turn it into blue. One way would be swapping the channels, but that's destructive because it's a change that you can't undo if you proceed unless you swap the channels back assuming no other colors are added or something. I wanna turn it to blue but keep all the levels.

Comment: @karl-police Where do you see red?  None of the edits shown in my examples are destructive. You can simply hide the adjustment layer to remove any effect.

Comment: @karl-police do you ean in the area that is not masked, sure thats whet the mask is showing you that you can only selectively apply this. Billy ditch the mask and it has not red (yellow is red)

Comment: @joojaa It's possible that my example is really bad, Though you are not getting the point. Look at the red channel https://i.imgur.com/eyuslk6.png There's red over the yellow. Yellow is also part of green. If you multiply the green channel with the red channel you obtain that bit of yellow, using the Channel Calculation thing. What you then obtain is this part https://i.imgur.com/SR5R3Td.png, which is present in the blue version https://i.imgur.com/bmtPVUM.png and I am questioning if there is a math way but also photoshop way to move further.

Comment: @karl-police - in RGB colours, yellow is a mixture of red and green.  There is no way to have any yellow without some red. It would just be green.

Comment: Yellow might be removing some info. But there's still red available that at the otherside of that yellow line and we know that it overlaps over green. So I was wondering if there's a way to get some sort of grayscale mask, that has all the levels of the red color and then somehow change it into blue. Even if it wouldn't be perfect, it's at least somewhat closer to the question.

Comment: @BillyKerr

With this result https://i.imgur.com/UrnLiUI.png we are not close to the output there's way more blue and the other one shifted away from the actual blue. We have not used the color level information from the red scale at all. Which is this part of information in the red channel. https://i.imgur.com/rOZSyzY.png

The blue output has exactly the same grayscale values. And I am wondering if there's a blending mode or something to create the same blue without manually doing it through RGB Channels, because I can't create adjustment layers on the RGB Channels.

Comment: @karl-police Sorry you lost me there. I now have absolutely no idea what you want, or even why.  This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: If you read that link, where it says "Others try to help user with Y, but are confused because Y seems like a strange problem to want to solve." This is the point that I am at so far. Now, explain why you want to do this? What are you actually trying to achieve here? What is it for?

Comment: When you want to replace colors or remove the outline of any solid colored background, you're always left with pixels that are mixed with a color. As example,  blue and red mixed together. And I believe that you can completly remove the green based on the RGB values or something. Which then you can use to get a full clear result.

A grayscale mask can have values that go from 255 to 0 where 255 is white and 0 is black. This defines the strength. Because the color adjustment layers don't seem to detect that by default at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149024/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-karl-police).